# Make "org-latex-preview" load package so that it properly renders "tcolorbox" environments

Tags: org-mode, latex

## The context

The following `org` buffer

```
* Random name

This is an equation

\begin{equation}
  x = a + b
\end{equation}

This is a box

\begin{tcolorbox}
  a
\end{tcolorbox}
```

is previewed as

[image: An Emacs buffer showing that the equation environment is properly rendered while the tcolorbox not. The previewing of the tcolorbox environment only displays its content but not the box at all]

## The question

Just as it is possible  to preview the content of a `equation` environment. Is it possible to preview the content of the `tcolorbox` envionment?

It seems that Emacs is not loading the `tcolorbox` environment. Is there  any way I can make Emacs load a given LaTeX package? so that when previewing a LaTeX code snippet that uses the `tcolorbox` environment, the actual content is displayed.

## Additional information

**Have you installed the `tcolorbox` package?**

Yes. I can confirm this because I've compiled several documents that uses the `tcolorbox` environment with `pdflatex` without any problems.

**Have you checked the variable `org-latex-packages-alist` contains the `tcolorbox` package?**

Yes. When describing the variable, I get the following value: `(("" "tcolorbox" t))`

**What's the value of the variable `org-preview-latex-default-process`?**

Its value is `dvipng`. This is the default value and I've not changed it.

**If you add `#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{tcolorbox}` at the top of your Org mode file and export to PDF. Do you see the box?**

Yes, I can see the box in the generated PDF file but still can't see when executing `org-latex-preview` within a `tcolorbox` environment. `tcolorbox`es are still being previewed as tiny empty boxes.

I tested this when `org-latex-packages-alist` was equal to `nil`.

**if you try to export without the header, is there a `\usepackage{tcolorbox}` in the generated `.tex` file?**

Without the header and with `org-latex-packages-alist` equal to `nil`, there is no `\usepackage{tcolorbox}`. However, the environment `tcolorbox` is used within the `.tex` file. In the resulting PDF file, only the text within the `tcolorbox` is rendered as normal text but no box is rendered.

Without the header and with `org-latex-packages-alist` equal to `(("" "tcolorbox" t))`, `\usepackage{tcolorbox}` does appears within the document. In the resulting PDF file, the `tcolorbox` environment is properly displayed (i.e. its content and the actual box).

**Post screenshoots of the tiny empty box**

Actually, it is not a tiny empty box. I wrote that because I tested it with a black background. Actually, the text within the `tcolorbox` is rendered in the preview but the box is not. See how the following Org file is previewed

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{tcolorbox}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{lipsum}

This is random text.

\begin{tcolorbox}
  a b c d
\end{tcolorbox}

This is random text

\begin{tcolorbox}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}

This is random text.
```

Preview and resulting PDF of the Org mode file shown above

[image]

This was tested when these variables had the following values

- `org-latex-packages-alist`: `nil`
- `org-preview-latex-default-process`: `dvipng`

Comment: There does seem to be a problem with `dvipng` (I use `imagemagick` as my org-preview-latex-default-process). I'll check some more when I have some time.

Comment: If you hve imagemagick installed, try it with that. If that works, then the problem is with the dvipng method.

Comment: Executed `(setq org-preview-latex-default-process 'imagemagick)` but now previewing can't occur because I'm getting the following error: `org-compile-file: File "/tmp/orgtexLO3Agf.png" wasn’t produced.  Please adjust ‘imagemagick’ part of ‘org-preview-latex-process-alist’.` I do have `imagemagick` installed in my system.

Comment: Solved the issue with [the help of an answer from this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31408/error-message-when-previewing-latex-snippet-in-org-file).  I had to used `imagemagick` instead of `dvipng` (by executing `(setq org-preview-latex-default-process 'imagemagick)`) and then modify the `/etc/ImageMagick-7/policy.xml` file as stated in an answer to the question. Thank you so much for your help @NickD. Please edit your answer so I can mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: Can you specify which answer you used: the one by Raoul Hatterer or the one by Alec Vercreysse? Or maybe another one? I added some info to the answer, but I was vague about what you really used to solve the problem.

Comment: The OS I'm using is Arch Linux. The version of `imagemagick` is `ImageMagick 7.0.10-29 Q16 x86_64` and the answer that helped me from that post was the one from [Raoul](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/48181/29861) but instead of editing `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` I had to edit `/etc/ImageMagick-7/policy.xml` since the version of `imagemagick` I'm using is `ImageMagick 7.0.10-29 Q16 x86_64`.

Comment: Thanks! I had the right answer but I will incorporate the extra information in my answer. I would ask you to do it, but I'm not sure what you are allowed to do at this point and what you are not, but you can try submitting an edit if you think that something could be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the package to `org-latex-packages-alist`:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'org
    (add-to-list 'org-latex-packages-alist '("" "tcolorbox" t)))
```

The `t` is important: it tells Org mode to include that package for LaTeX preview. Otherwise, it will only be included when you export the file to LaTeX/PDF, but not when previewing LaTeX fragments.

*EDIT*: There seem to be problems with the `dvipng` setting of `org-preview-latex-default-process` that require more investigation.

Setting the process to `imagemagick` with

```
(setq org-preview-latex-default-process 'imagemagick)
```

works out of the box for me (ImageMagick-6 on Fedora 31), but it did not work for the OP (ImageMagick-7 on Arch Linux). Apparently, the `/etc/ImageMagick-7/policy.xml` file imposed some restriction on permissions that prevented the conversion of the PDF file to a PNG file (the `imagemagick` process uses `pdflatex` to convert the TeX file to PDF and then uses the `convert` program from ImageMagick to convert the PDF to PNG).  The OP reports that he was able to solve the problem from an answer
to [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31408/error-message-when-previewing-latex-snippet-in-org-file): [this one](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/48181/14825).

*EDIT*: To debug problems:

- have you installed the `tcolorbox` package?
- check the value of `org-latex-packages-alist` - does it contain the `tcolorbox` entry (with a `t` as shown above)? Use `C-h v org-latex-packages-alist RET` to get the value.
- check the value of `org-preview-latex-default-process` with `C-h v org-preview-latex-default-process` and update the question with it.
- add `#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{tcolorbox}` at the top of your Org mode file and export to PDF. Do you see the box?
- if you try to export without the header, is there a `\usepackage{tcolorbox}` in the generated `.tex` file?
- check the `ltximg/` subdirectory for images and view each one. You might want to delete them and run the preview again: that's the only way to make sure they are up-to-date.
- use [edebug](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Debugging.html#Debugging) or `M-x debug-on-entry` to stop execution at the beginning of `org-compile-file` and then step through it to figure out what Org mode is doing, so you can save the generated file(s) and you can try to reproduce the process by hand.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work: I executed that command, killed the Org buffer, opened it again, and executed `org-latex-preview` within the `tcolorbox` environment but it was displayed as a tiny empty box. Did this solution worked on your Emacs setup?

Comment: Yes it works. I added some debugging suggestions to the answer.

Comment: I've already edited my answer with that information.