# How to generate a PNG from a TikZ figure with org-babel?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I'm try to use org-babel to generate images from tikz code.

The first code (take from [this example](https://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/%7Eucahjde/blog/tikz.html)) works perfectly, but when y want to export the tikz figure in  a png (or a jpg) I have an error like :

```
org-compile-file: File "/tmp/babel-RNLDyr/latex-o3rO8d.pdf" wasn’t produced.  See "*Org PDF LaTeX Output*" for details
```

I can't find the cause of this error and the "*Org PDF LaTeX Output*" buffer does not exists.

Code use to make a svg (It's work) :

```lisp
#+HEADER: :file ./images/contour.svg :imagemagick yes
#+HEADER: :results output silent :headers '("\\usepackage{tikz}")
#+HEADER: :fit yes :imoutoptions -geometry 400 :iminoptions -density 600
#+BEGIN_src latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-3,0) -- (-2,0) arc[radius=0.5cm,start angle=-180,end angle=0] (-1,0) -- (1,0) arc[radius=0.5cm,start angle=180,end angle=0] (2,0) -- (3,0);
\filldraw (-1.5,0) circle[radius=1mm];
\filldraw (1.5,0) circle[radius=1mm];
\end{tikzpicture}
#+END_src
```

Code use to make a png (It does not work) :

```lisp
#+HEADER: :file ./images/contour.png :imagemagick yes
#+HEADER: :results output silent :headers '("\\usepackage{tikz}")
#+HEADER: :fit yes :imoutoptions -geometry 400 :iminoptions -density 600
#+BEGIN_src latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-3,0) -- (-2,0) arc[radius=0.5cm,start angle=-180,end angle=0] (-1,0) -- (1,0) arc[radius=0.5cm,start angle=180,end angle=0] (2,0) -- (3,0);
\filldraw (-1.5,0) circle[radius=1mm];
\filldraw (1.5,0) circle[radius=1mm];
\end{tikzpicture}
#+END_src
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to generate a PNG image of TikZ with the following minimal reproducible example.

In the GIF shown below, you can see that I execute `emacs` by using the `-Q` flag and by loading Lisp code present in the `main.el` file. The image is generated from the file `main.org` without any problem.

The following code block shows the content of the `main.org` file

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{tikz}

#+begin_src latex :file main.png :results file graphics
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw node[circle, draw] (a) {$a$}
        node[circle, draw, right of = a] (b) {$b$}
        node[circle, draw, below of = a] (c) {$c$}
        node[circle, draw, below of = b] (d) {$d$};
\end{tikzpicture}
#+end_src
```

The following code block shows the content of the `main.el` file

```
; The following configuration sets the font (demostration purposes)

(set-frame-font "Iosevka SS04 Light 30")

; The following configuration make Org Mode use imagemagick for processing images.
;
; This was retrieved from this question (https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/60696) I posted.

(setq org-preview-latex-default-process 'imagemagick)

; The following configuration disables the confirmation prompt whenever code blocks are evaluated.

(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil)

; The following hook make images to be shown after code blocks are executed.

(add-hook 'org-babel-after-execute-hook 'org-redisplay-inline-images)

; The following configuration allows code blocks whose language is latex to be evaluated

(org-babel-do-load-languages 'org-babel-load-languages
                 '((latex . t)))
```

[image]

Comment: It's work, tanks. I don't know why, but the content of the ```:headers``` parameter does not seem to be used when the output file is a PNG. It's works using the ```#+LATEX_HEADER``` variable.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, using

```
#+HEADER: :results file graphics
```

instead of

```
#+HEADER: :results output silent
```

The complete code is:

```
#+HEADER: :file contour.png :imagemagick yes
#+HEADER: :results file graphics :headers '("\\usepackage{tikz}") 
#+HEADER: :fit yes :imoutoptions -geometry 400 :iminoptions -density 600
#+BEGIN_src latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-3,0) -- (-2,0) arc[radius=0.5cm,start angle=-180,end angle=0] (-1,0) -- (1,0) arc[radius=0.5cm,start angle=180,end angle=0] (2,0) -- (3,0);
\filldraw (-1.5,0) circle[radius=1mm];
\filldraw (1.5,0) circle[radius=1mm];
\end{tikzpicture}
#+END_src
```

[image]