# Why LaTeX preview doesn't work in org-mode for mhchem snippets?

Tags: org-mode, latex, preview-latex

I'm facing a very similar issue as per question [Make "org-latex-preview" load package so that it properly renders "tcolorbox" environments](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/60696/39427), using the `mhchem` latex package (version 4.09).

I'm using Emacs 28.1, org-mode 9.5.5, pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22, ImageMagick 6.9.12 running on Fedora 37.

`org-latex-packages-alist` is set to '`(("version=4" "mhchem" t))`

I have tried setting `org-preview-latex-default-process` to `dvipng`, `dvisvgm` or `imagemagick`.

When the org file is exported to latex and PDF, the `mhchem` syntax is correctly interpreted and exported. And when calling `org-latex-preview` on `\(2 + 3\)` a preview is correctly generated. However, when calling `org-latex-preview` on `\ce{Na2CO4}` nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by wrapping `\ce{Na2CO4}` with `\(…\)`.

However, I'm still confused on why this is necessary, as `\alpha{}` of `\pm{}` get correctly “prettified” in α and ± without `\(\)`.

Comment: Not when you preview: `\alpha` and `\pm` stay as they are. They are not `LaTeX fragments` in the way that [Org mode understands that term](https://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-fragments.html): explicit environments or things surrounded by math delimiters. Exporting is a different matter: there Org mode transcodes `\alpha` into `\( \alpha \)` and `\pm` into `\textpm` because the exporter "knows"  that these things only make sense within a math environment  - taking a look at the resulting `LaTeX` file should prove enlightening.

Comment: BTW, the exporter "knows" these things through the [`org-entities` table](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/org-entities.el). The doc string of that variable and the related `org-entities-user` will tell you what the various columns mean.

Comment: Thank you @NickD