# org mode embedded LaTeX does not work for packages imported using usepackage?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I have used org mode [embedded LaTeX](https://orgmode.org/manual/Embedded-LaTeX.html) for a while. The commonly used syntax such as subscripts, fractions and math symbols works well out of the box. All that is needed is to put the LaTeX content between $ signs. The LaTeX formula even shows correctly when the org-mode file is exported to MS Word format (via pandoc).

However, the translation of embedded LaTeX does not seem to work if I import an external package and use the commands therein. Here is an example org file with one set of LaTeX commands, copied from this [TeX exchange example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5568/113426):

```
#+LATEX_HEADER_EXTRA: \usepackage{mathpartir}

\begin{mathpar}
\inferrule* [left=Total]
  {\inferrule* [Left=Foo] {\inferrule* [Right=Bar,
                              leftskip=2em,rightskip=2em,vdots=1.5em]
      {a \\ a \\\\ bb \\ cc \\ dd}
      {ee}
    \\ ff \\ gg}
    {hh}
    \\
    \inferrule* [lab=XX]{uu \\ vv}{ww}}
    {(1)}
\end{mathpar}
```

When previewed with `C-c C-x C-l`, it shows an incomplete rendering:

[image]

instead of the tree it is supposed to display (replicated below).

[image]

Note: Thanks to @Ian's comments, I fixed an error in the example and used an environment. But the preview still does not work, nor does the export (via pandoc) to MS Word (same result as in the screenshot). The only thing that works is to export it to PDF (via pandoc). By the way, copying the content to a .tex file (and removing `LATEX_HEADER_EXTRA`) does show the correct rendering in the exported PDF.

My question is:

*How to configure the org-mode file so that the LaTeX fragment involving an external package can be rendered correctly as embedded images?*

Note: Ideally, this should produce the same results as regular formulae, so that they can be exported to other document types such as MS Word. And this is Emacs 29, org-mode 9.6.6 under Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: After declaring the header ```usepackage{mathpartir}``` you need to declare the environment ```\begin{mathpar} .... \end{mathpar} in which you will enclose your infer rule. Nothing else to configure.

Comment: @Ian Thanks a lot for your help. I added the environment declaration, and updated the question. The figure is correct now in the PDF output, but the embedded LaTeX preview image and exported .docx is still incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search, this seems to be the same problem as described in this [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/60698/17852) with a different package and environment.

The steps I had to do are:

1. Add the LaTeX package `mathpartir` to `'org-latex-packages-alist` in `init.el`:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'org
    ; ...
    (add-to-list 'org-latex-packages-alist '("" "mathpartir" t))
    )
```

2. Change the latex preview program to `imagemagick` in init.el

```
(setq org-preview-latex-default-process 'imagemagick)
```

3. install imagemagick in Ubuntu:

   sudo apt install imagemagick
4. edit the imagemagick policy `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` and change the line

`<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" />`

to

`<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />`

Then, after deleting the cached preview png images `ltximg/org-ltximg_*`, org-mode is able to generate the correct preview image.